# Why does the initializer_list does not violate the rule of "One Class-Type Conversion"

Tags: c++, c++11

The **"One Class-Type Conversion" Rule** is quoted from c++ Primer 5th § 7.5.4

> **Only One Class-Type Conversion Is Allowed**
>   In § 4.11.2 (p. 162) we noted that the compiler will automatically **apply only one class-type conversion.** For example, the following code is in error because it implicitly uses two conversions:

```
     //item.combine() need a parameter of class Sales_data,which has a constructor of string type;
     item.combine("9-999-99999-9");
    // error: requires two user-defined conversions:
    // (1) convert "9-999-99999-9" to string
    // (2) convert that (temporary) string to Sales_data
```

The code above cause error because it violate the **rule of "One Class-Type Conversion";**
And here is an introduction of [Implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion)
Based on the rule above,I came across 2 questions in studying c++,both of them are **copy initialization**,which means that the **copy constructor** will be called .

### example of `string`

Considering the code snippet `string a="hello";`,if we does not think about the fact that the compiler will often do some optimization like **copy elision**, then the code is interpreted like :

1. convert the type of `"hello"` from `char[6]` to `char*`; **(convert 1)**
2. call the constructor of `string(char*)` and generate a temporary `string`  object `temp`   **(convert 2)**
3. call the copy constructor of `string(string&&)`,and finally get `a`

**Question:** OK,actually **2 convertion** happens,why does that not violate the **"One Class-Type Conversion" Rule**? Is it because the conversion from `char[6]` to `char*` is not a **class-type** conversion,since the `char*` is not **class-type** but a **built-in type** ?

### example of `initializer_list`

once we use a list initialization of `vector` like

```
 vector<int> example={1,2,3,4,5};
```

then the code is interpreted like :

1. `{1,2,3,4,5}` does not have a type like "hello",so there is no conversion like `char[6]` to `char*`
2. convert `{1,2,3,4,5}` to temporary object of `initializer_list<int> temp`(**convert 1**)
3. convert `initializer_list<int> temp` to `vector<int> temp1` by using:(**convert 2**)

   ```
   vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
   ```
4. call the copy constructor of `vector( vector&& other );`,and finally we get `vector<int> example` ;

**Question:** Ooop!There are also **2 conversion** happening! And there are all conversions of **class-type**! What happened?

Comment: Where you see **call the copy constructor of vector( vector&& other )** from?

Comment: @S.M. see [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: You missed `vector& operator=( std::initializer_list<T> ilist );`

Comment: @S.M. Yes,i know there is a copy assinment,but in the semantic of copy initialization ,it will call the copy constructor,not the copy assignment

Comment: Copy (moving) is not converting in any case.

Comment: @S.M. But as far as I know,copy initialization is equivalent to calling the copy constructor,which is actually a function. So I think the **one class-type conversion** rule should also take effect in such situation

Comment: @S.M. See my own ansewer.

Comment: Your *convert {..} to initializer_list; convert initializer_list to vector<int>* bullets have it wrong. The way it works that the compiler already looks into `vector<int>` prior to conversions, and then `{..}` constructs the constructor parameter of `vector<int>`, rather than an autonomous `initializer_list`. In that respect, it's more similar to `vector<int> example(...)` rather than `= ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,since an hour passed and nobody here has answered this question,i've found the answer myself.

### example of string

The reson is that `char[5]` to `char*` is not a **class-type** conversion,so it does not violate the **One Class-Type Conversion** rule.

> **Order of the conversions**
>   Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>   1) zero or one standard conversion sequence;
>   2) zero or one user-defined conversion;
>   3) zero or one standard conversion sequence.
>   When considering the argument to a constructor or to a user-defined conversion function, only one standard conversion sequence is allowed (otherwise user-defined conversions could be effectively chained). When converting from one built-in type to another built-in type, only one standard conversion sequence is allowed.

### example of initializer_list

`initializer_list` is a special case,which is actually **copy-list-initializaition** but not **copy-initialization**,so there are no **2 type conversion here**.  See [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> - Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>     **All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument**, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type std::initializer_list

So when we use a initializer_list,there is no conversion from **other to T**,which is a requirement for **copy-constructor** . See [Copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

> If T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type, but the type of other is a class type, user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the **type of other to T** (or to a type derived from T if T is a class type and a conversion function is available) are examined and the best one is selected through overload resolution. **The result of the conversion** , which is a prvalue temporary (until C++17)prvalue expression (since C++17) if a converting constructor was used, is then used to direct-initialize the object. The last step is usually optimized out and the result of the conversion is constructed directly in the memory allocated for the target object, **but the appropriate constructor (move or copy) is required to be accessible even though it's not used. (until C++17)**

So the constructor with parameter `initializer_list<int>` will be directly called,but not the `move/copy` constructor.Hence the example also doesn't violate the **One Class-Type Conversion** Rule.